# Detect if UIKeyBoard is Showing

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard

I'd like to detect whether or not the keyboard is showing.  I've found a few other posts that traverse the subviews of UIWindow to find the keyboard, but if that is the only way then I'll figure out something else.  I suppose I could also observe the UIKeyboard notifications, but I'm guessing there is a cleaner solution out there.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure what's "dirty" in observing UIKeyboard notifications but it definitely beats traversing UIWindow hierarchy.