# Programmatically check if iPhone keyboard is on screen or not

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programatically check whether a keyboard is present in iphone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490573/how-to-programatically-check-whether-a-keyboard-is-present-in-iphone-app)
>   [Detect if UIKeyBoard is Showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903987/detect-if-uikeyboard-is-showing)

Is there a way to programmatically check if the iPhone's keyboard is on screen or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, you want to add an `NSNotificationCenter` observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: I don't want it to necessarily call a function upon receiving the notification, though, I just want it to check before it adds a subview. It'll affect the frame of the subview.

Comment: Oh wait, never mind. I can just change the value of a boolean. Thanks!

Comment: You can set the `selector` to **`nil`**, but how else do you expect to know when it appears?